# Short, but actually pretty sweet, riddle

Tags: riddle

> Anointed Lord of the Crystal Mountain
>   wields a book of human skin.
>   He knows who you love,
>   has a key to your box
>   and can strap you to a lucid dream.

Hint:

> It might be easier to start with the second line.

Comment: Does this require knowledge of some trivia (books, games, ...) in order to solve it?

Comment: @randal'thor No, not this time. (I would have marked it with [tag:knowledge] if it did.) It might require some general knowledge, but I don't think that's anything obscure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it

> Mark Zuckerberg

Anointed Lord of the Crystal Mountain

> Zucker berg = sugar mountain (and perhaps crystal refers to sugar crystals?)

wields a book of human skin.

> Facebook

He knows who you love,

> FaceBook Graph?

has a key to your box

> Encryption?

and can strap you to a lucid dream.

> Augmented Reality app?

Comment: This is the correct answer! You got everything right except for the box part - it refers to mailbox, since the {second line} asks people to give it their login and password for their e-mail so it can scrape it for known addresses. No, I don't mean by open-authentication style scheme, I mean by literally filling them in a form and handing them over to {second line}, which is presumably saved and reused.

Comment: Also: anointing is a kind of marking, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

U r a...

> b

---

Anointed Lord of the Crystal Mountain

> Bees make honey which contains sugar, which is a crystal, making them the lords of ... sugar mountain

wields a book of human skin.

> Man-made beehives have a book-like structure of slats containing beeswax which is chemically similar to human skin at a wax museum

He knows who you love,

> **Be**loved

has a key to your box

> **B**ox

and can strap you to a lucid dream.

> "Honey at Bedtime for More Vivid Dreams"

Comment: To be fair, this is pretty much Eric's answer

Comment: Which is pretty much Silenus's answer

Comment: This is pretty creative, but it's pretty far off the mark, and it's not the right answer. ... Oh no, I've dropped a hint!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are

> SUGAR.

---

Anointed Lord of the Crystal Mountain

> Sugar is an important crystal.

wields a book of human skin.

> Not sure.

He knows who you love,

> This may refer to the fact that some people call their partner's "sugar".

has a key to your box

> Sugar is found in many processed food.

and can strap you to a lucid dream.

> Some claim that sugar induces lucid dreaming.

Title:

> The title includes a pun on the word *sweet*.

Comment: You are on the right track - you have deciphered half of the meaning behind first verse and the title - but this is not the answer. A question that might help you: what kind of material could count as human skin?

Comment: For the allusion to human skin - *palm sugar*?

Comment: Other candidates for "human skin": fabric, clothes, armor, makeup, basically any worn outer layer.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're

> Honey

Anointed Lord of the Crystal Mountain

> Honey contains sugar, a crystal. In a way, honey is like an *anointment * on sugar.

wields a book of human skin.

> Um... maybe it's referring to a honeycomb? Not sure.

He knows who you love,

> Lot of people call their bf/gf/wife/husband "Honey"

has a key to your box

> Not sure

and can strap you to a lucid dream.

> Probably something about how sweets can cause lucid dreams

And finally...

> The title includes the word sweet

Comment: Good try, but you went in the wrong direction compared to Silenus' answer. I really like how the first two answers interpreted the `who you love` verse in the same way, but it's not about that. As for the first verse: anointment is not related or a part of lordship.

Comment: RIP alright, i'll think about it

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I've quite got it, as not everything matches each other, but I can manage to get it around a central theme, so I'm sure there are better matches than I've found thus far.

Are you

> iPhone/iDevice

Anointed Lord of the Crystal Mountain

> iPhones are an industry leader in smart phones, which utilize LCDs (liquid **crystal** display)

wields a book of human skin.

> Your contact book (contains many faces)

He knows who you love,

> Tracks most frequently contacted people, and contacts manually marked as favorites

has a key to your box

> You can check your e-mail (inbox) from your iPhone

and can strap you to a lucid dream.

> This may be a reference to the [iBand+](http://www.ibandplus.com/), purported to induce lucid dreaming, although it is not an Apple product.

Title:

> Most iDevices are by Apple, and apples taste sweet.

Comment: Wow, that's a good one - it's the most fitting of all the incorrect answers so far. However, the correct answer was given by shree.pat18.